# Magento ?SID key being inserted into wordpress anchor tags containing hashes

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, magento

I've used the same jQuery on a number of sites to make a page scroll to the relevant section without ever having an issue. However I'm updating a wordpress blog site which uses Magento headers and footers which seems to be removing the wp directory and inserting ?SID keys to the links and the jQuery is being ignored.

Is there a way to stop this (I don't have access to the magento install).

Site urls:

- the-url.com (magento install)
- the-url.com/blog (wordpress install)

Links being generated:

- the-url.com/?SID=cnndbpsb9mdmsj5d6vch049f83#brand

jQuery:

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<ul class="fixednav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#brand">Brand</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's get # value from the url after the # url string like '#brand' its just take 'brand' from it .

```
 var url ='www.site.com/?SID=cnndbpsb9mdmsj5d6vch049f83#brand';   
    var type = url.split('#');
    var hash = '';
    if(type.length > 1)
        hash = type[1];
    //this will alert the hash value from the url 
    alert(hash);
   //then use the hash value for scroll with on click function this is just an example 
    var offset=jQuery('#'+hash).offset().top-40;
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:offset }, 2000);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)